# What is the difference between ` inline friend ...... ` functions and `friend inline .....` functions?

Tags: c++, inline, friend

When I am checking declarations from string.h file, I saw these things:

```
friend inline void     cat(const String&,const SubString&,const String&,String&);
inline friend void     cat(const String&,const SubString&,const String&,String&);
```

What is the difference between them?

Comment: They differ in the 3rd parameter type.

Comment: the list of parameters are different, other than that, they are the same. You can do "inline friend" or "friend inline"

Comment: do you mean `inline friend` and `friend inline` make no difference

Comment: The file name `string.h` has nothing to do with the question. It could be `str42.h` or `cacti_are_cool.h`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no difference. Both `friend` and `inline` are independent declaration specifiers, which can be specified in any order.

There's not much point in declaring the function `inline` in a friend declaration though. More generally, there's no point in specifying `inline` in any *non-defining* function declaration. `inline` makes more sense when applied to a function *definition*.

Answer (score 0):

The `friend` and `inline` modifiers can be used independently, and their order has no impact. E.g., `inline friend foo()` is the same as `friend inline foo()`.

Comment: and inline function means function can be used in the functions defined in same file. Right?

Comment: @MadhuKumar no. `inline` is a hint to the compiler to replace the function call with its implementation (i..e, to *inline* it). Theoretically, this should provide some performance benefit, especially if the function is short, so the code doesn't get bloated (see also http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline)

Comment: The original post was edited; now the parameters are the same.

Comment: @DanKorn edited away the piece about overloading, which, as you noted, no longer relates to the question.